# Problems with langutil in Common Lisp - how to tokenize a file

Tags: lisp, nlp, common-lisp, tokenize

I've been trying to tokenize a string using the langutils library (which I downloaded using Quicklisp) and I'm using SBCL, but I've been having a few problems. I've been trying to use the following code:

`(cl-utilities:split-sequence #\Space (multiple-value-call #'(lambda (a b c d) c) (tokenize-stream (open "hello.txt"))))`

with the output

`("Hello" "," "" "what" "is" "your" "name." "My" "name" "is" "John" "Doe.")`

My question is: why is langutils tokenizing a space, and why is it not tokenizing the periods?

As an aside, if langutils is buggy, are there any other alternative libraries in Common Lisp that I can use? I've tried to use (tokenize-file), but it isn't working as well - using (tokenize-file "hello.txt") returns

`The function LANGUTILS-TOKENIZE:TOKENIZE-FILE is undefined.`

and using (tag "string") returns

`The value NIL is not of type HASH-TABLE.`

Comment: Try calling `(langutils:init-langutils)` before using `langutils:tag`. `(nth-value 2 (tokenize...))` is a slightly easier way to write your `multiple-value-call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets see, in no particular order:

---

Yes, `langutils` seems buggy. And taking a look at its source, quite a few things are still labelled "(not implemented yet)". What are you trying to do with it? Specifically, what do you expect `(tag "string")` and `tokenize-file` to do (the docstring wasn't particularly clear)?

If you're going to be trying to parse Lisp expressions, you can use the built-in `read`. If you're going to be trying to parse arbitrary files with their own syntax rules (and are using SBCL), take a look at [`esrap`](https://nikodemus.github.io/esrap/). It's a PEG parser implementation in Common Lisp. The [github](https://github.com/nikodemus/esrap) has some examples.

---

If you want to omit empty sequences from `split-sequence`, you can pass it the additional `:remove-empty-subseqs` keyword argument. I'm not entirely sure why this isn't the default, since I've never called the function without this option, but it's possible that it makes sense in whatever the primary use-case was.

Your call should look like

```
(cl-utilities:split-sequence 
 #\Space (multiple-value-call #'(lambda (a b c d) c)
       (tokenize-stream (open "hello.txt")))
 :remove-empty-subseqs t)
```

---

`tokenize-stream` seems to return the text contents of a file, along with some metadata about it. If that's all you want, it's pretty easy to write your own without resorting to `multiple-value-call`. See the [Files and Directories section of the CL Cookbook](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/files.html)

---

I think by doing `(tokenize-stream (open "hello.txt"))`, you're leaving a file handle dangling (since you're not closing it afterwards). The typical thing to do here is to call `with-open-file`

```
(with-open-file (s "hello.txt")
  (tokenize-stream s))
```

Comment: To answer your first question, I expected (tag "string") to return the part of speech tag of the string.
Next, what actually tokenize-stream is supposed to do is to tokenize the text contents of a file - for instance, in a sentence "I have an appt. but you do not.", the correct tokenization is ("I" "have" "an" "appt." "but" "you" "do" "not" "."). With that being said I think I'll just try to implement it myself, and I think that using remove-empty-subseqs along with removing non-alphanumeric characters (besides periods in some cases) should work out anyway.

Comment: @user124577 - If that's what you want out of `tag`, you might look into the [parts of speech](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html) database. There may be more comprehensive datasets out there, but that's one I've used to play around before.